# Problem assigning javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Is there any way to assign an object property like pear below? (example doesn't work)

```
var fruitColors = { apple: "green", pear: fruitColors.apple};
```

I can achieve it by doing this however, but I'd like to do it like above if it's possible.

```
var fruitColors = { apple: "green" };
fruitColors.pear = fruitColors.apple;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can - as the fruitColors object doesn't exist at the time you are trying to access it's property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it during initialization. You could make a constructor if you wanted, but not sure if it would be worth it.

```
function FruitColors() {
    this.apple = "green";
    this.pear = this.apple;
}

var fruitColors = new FruitColors;
```

or in newer implementations, you could use the `get` syntax to make `pear` reference `apple`:

```
var fruitColors = { 
    apple: "green",
    get pear() { return this.apple; }
}
```

but this isn't widely supported across browsers if that's your target.